# For loop plot() vs ggplot() - ggplot() not working?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using Iris dataset in R.

I have the following code

```
for (i in colnames(iris[-5])) {
  
  plot(iris$Species, iris[[i]],
       xlab = 'Species',
       ylab = `i`)
                    
}
```

This prints out 4 boxplot.
I want to do the same in ggplot with the following code

```
for (i in colnames(iris[-5])) {
  
  print(iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = i)))
                    
}
```

When I do this in ggplot, the boxplots look messed up. Is it just my R or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcom to the wonderful world of tidyverse non-standard evaluation ([NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)).  I think `geom_boxplot(aes(y = !!sym(i))))`  will give you what you want, after correcting the obvious typo in your code.  By the way "look messed up" isn't terribly helpful. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just change `aes(y=i)` to `aes_string(y=i)`, and of course, use `geom_boxplot` instead of `geom_col`